# Block access to files in a folder and hide files' names

Tags: security

I am looking for a solution to hide file contained in a folder, block access and hide even file names.

I've been able to achieve the first and second result using Axcrypt but my file names still can be seen...

Any hints?

Comment: What's the difference between hiding a file and hiding a file name?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear: I need that instead of the file name "textfile.txt" it reads "xxxxxx.xxx" or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Blocking read access to the folder itself will hide all the filenames in that folder - this is the simplest way to do it under Windows or Unix.

Use access controls to only allow access to specified users/accounts.

Comment: The problem is that is a shared computer and both people use the same username/password so the problem should be solved using an utility like axcrypt

Comment: how can you distinguish between users if they use the same username?